# How to read csv file into map in scala

Tags: scala

I have data in csv like this:

```
Name, Price
Apple, 2.00
Banana, 3.00
Pear, 2.50
```

I would like to produce the following map:

```
Map("Apple" -> 2.00, "Banana" ->3.00, "Pear" ->2.50)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know at least how to read the file?

Comment: I do know how to read the file like this: Source.fromFile("Items.csv").getLines()

Comment: @EdwardKong ok now you need to process those lines to produce the map you want, do you have an idea of the pseudo-code of what you want to do?

Comment: no, what I'm trying to do is to get the price of an item in the csv file by using map, like I want to get price of Apple, it would give me 2.00

Comment: @EdwardKong yeah but the first step is to build the map, you need to think how would you do that. Write a pseudo-code and then try to write cod,e if you got stuck you can edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll throw here a start of an idea:

```
val csv = Source.fromFile("/path/a.csv").getLines().map(_.split(",") match {
      case Array(a, b) =>
        a.trim -> Try(b.trim.toDouble)
      case _ => ???
    }).filter(_._2.isSuccess).toMap
```